# Код javascript (jquery), событие on click срабатывает через раз (или реже) в virtualbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

В php разделил ip адрес пользователя (взял первые числа до точки ip адреса):

```
$ip = explode(".",$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])[0];
```

На javascript делал генератор случайных чисел от 100 до 1000:

```
function randomIntegerone(min, max) {
    var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
    rand = Math.round(rand);
    return rand;
}
```

Подставил таким образом:

```
var sdivx = randomIntegerone(100, 1000)+переменный $ip 
(суммировал случайное число из javascript с переменным $ip языка php);
```

Далее у нас атрибут id тега body переделается так:

```
if(document.querySelector("body").getAttribute("id") == "sdiv"){
document.querySelector("body").setAttribute("id","sdiv"+sdivx);
}
```

Но если кликнуть по ссылке этого тега, то наш код либо срабатывает, либо нет:

```
$("html").on("click","#sdiv"+sdivx+" a",
function(){
$.post("/sdivhandler.php",{subdiv:1},function(a){console.log(a)})
}
)
```

В компьютере (и ноутбуке) отлично работает, а вот в virtualbox (windows 8 mozilla firefox, последняя версия) и т.п. срабатывает через раз (а может и реже).
В чем может быть причина?

P.S. Вот так отлично работает в virtualbox (всегда alert выскакивает):

```
$("html").on("click","#sdiv"+sdivx+" a",
function(){
alert("hello world");
}
)
```

Отдельно запрос тоже отлично работает (в virtualbox):

```
$.post("/sdivhandler.php",{subdiv:1},function(a){console.log(a)})
```

Но если их вместе запустить в virtualbox то работает, то нет (в консоле ошибок нет).

Comment: Скорее всего дело в самом событии `onclick`. Уберите все манипуляции с random, ip, сложными селекторами. Поставьте простой слушатель на событие `onclick` на `body` и смотрите, как он выполняется. Потом добавьте информацию в вопрос, что получилось.

Comment: Убрал все random, ip, та же ситуация (в компьютере все работает, а в virtualbox в firefox не всегда). visual event в firefox изменении событий показывает (т.е. я точно знаю что при клике он должен был срабатывать, но почему-то не срабатывает или еще что-то). Или я неправильно проверяю (прослушиваю) событии? Сразу скажу, что без всяких событий, т.е. если оставить только это: function(){
$.post("/sdivhandler.php",{subdiv:1},function(a){console.log(a)})
} то он всегда работает, поэтому причина только в событии.

Comment: Поправьте ваш вопрос, покажите код, который у вас есть без random, ip. Также, вместо запуска запросов, просто выведите в консоль сообщение.

Comment: поправил вопрос.Без random и ip это так: $("html").on("click","#sdiv a",function(){$.post("/sdivhandler.php",{subdiv:1},function(a){console.log(a)})}) Так тоже самое работает (через раз), проверил. В консоле ничего нет, только то, что я сам вывел

Comment: Могу предположить, что происходит следующее. Virtualbox не в фокусе. Вы нажимаете на body в мозиле, Virtualbox получает фокус, но событие onclick в мозиле не срабатывает. Потом событие onclick работает как положено, пока Virtualbox  снова не потеряет фокус. Так работает?

Comment: Я тоже так думал, но все равно что-то не то (проверил). Кто-то посоветовал вместо id сделать class, так тоже через раз или реже работает.

Comment: а запрос всегда отправляется?

Comment: да, если событие убрать и оставить только $.post("/sdivhandler.php",{subdiv:1},function(a){console.log(a)}) то всегда отправляется

Comment: В таком случае делайте исследование, при каких условиях событие не срабатывает. Главное - найти причину.

Comment: попробуйте выводить алерт + отправлять запрос, и посмотрите синхронизированы ли они

Comment: кстати да. Пробовал делать так: алерт + запрос, так запрос не срабатывает (только алерт срабатывает). 
Сделал наоборот: запрос + алерт, то запрос всегда срабатывает (вместе с алертом). Логически можно подумать что пока до алерта не доберется все запросы заработают. 
Как без алерта и прочих костылей запустить?

Comment: вы пока алерт не отожмете, вообще ничего не будет работать. Он блокирует поток выполнения, это норма. Раз обычный алерт срабатывает всегда, то возможно проблема не в клике, а в запросе. А вы смотрели в `network`?

Comment: Если только запрос запустить, то всегда срабатывает, как и alert. В обычном компьютере в network выполняется скрипт из файла /sdivhandler.php (даже вижу какая именно часть срабатывает)
А на виртуальном ОС в network не появляется этот sdivhandler.php (естественно и не срабатывает)

Comment: А зачем вы меняете атрибут ID, может лучше использовать data-, с ним ведь удобнее

Comment: @Ilnyr, Ошибки есть какие-то? Есть логи сервера (что запрос не пришёл ни в каком виде)? Сам сервер на той же виртуалке? Что в нетворке есть (любые запросы). Какое поведение у хрома?

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее вероятно что вы пытаетесь повешать обработчик события на элемент, который не успел обновиться в DOM. 
Есть как минимум два варианта:

1) **Костыль c задержкой**

```
if(document.querySelector("body").getAttribute("id") == "sdiv"){
    document.querySelector("body").setAttribute("id","sdiv"+sdivx);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("html").on("click","#sdiv"+sdivx+" a", function(){
            $.post("/sdivhandler.php",{subdiv:1},function(a){console.log(a)})
        });
    }, 100);
}
```

**Плюсы:**

- можно быстро написать

**Минусы:**

- может работать, а может и нет.
- зависит от геомагнитной обстановки на планете

2) **Наблюдатель мутаций аттрибутов дом элемента**

```
var target = document.getElementById('sdiv');
var config = { attributes: true, childList: false, characterData: false };

// создаём экземпляр MutationObserver
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  $(mutations[0].target).find('a').on("click", function(){
       $.post("/sdivhandler.php",{subdiv:1},function(a){console.log(a)});
  });  
  //После установки обработчика отключаемся от прослушки; 
  this.disconnect();
});

// передаём в качестве аргументов целевой элемент и его конфигурацию
observer.observe(target, config);
```

**Плюсы:**

- гарантированно получаете измененный DOM элемент

**Минусы:**

- не работает в IE < 11